# What does experimental in TensorFlow mean?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

In [TensorFlow 2.0 APIs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf), there is a module `tf.experimental`. Such a name also appears in other places like `tf.data.experimental`. I just would like to know what the motivation for designing these modules is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tf.experimental` indicates that the said class/method is in early development, incomplete, or less commonly, not up-to-standards. It's a collection of user contributions which weren't yet integrated w/ main TensorFlow, but are still available as a part of open-source for users to test and give feedback.

"Incomplete" is the most common, which can include having bugs, or not passing tests across a required set of platforms or hardware (CPU/GPU). As an example of not being "up to standards", from a 2017 Google Devs [blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/xla-tensorflow-compiled.html) on `tf.xla.experimental`: (more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726528/why-is-tensorflow-xla-in-experimental-status))

> XLA should still be considered experimental, and some benchmarks may experience slowdowns