# When to use model.predict(x) vs model(x) in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've got a `keras.models.Model` that I load with `tf.keras.models.load_model`.

Now there are two options to use this model. I can call `model.predict(x)` or I can call `model(x).numpy()`. Both options give me the same result, but `model.predict(x)` takes over 10x longer to run.

The comments in the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/564b53c86efe1d6fa5ad40c4900e41f2967fa73d/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L843) state:

> Computation is done in batches. This method is designed for performance in
>       **large scale inputs**. For small amount of inputs that fit in one batch,
>       directly using `__call__` is recommended for faster execution, e.g.,
>       `model(x)`, or `model(x, training=False)`

I've tested with `x` containing 1; 1,000,000; and 10,000,000 rows and `model(x)` still performs better.

How large does the input need to be to be classified as a large scale input, and for the `model.predict(x)` to perform better?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58378374/why-does-keras-model-predict-slower-after-compile/#answer-58385156) may be of help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an existing stack overflow answer that you might find useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58385156/5666087. I found it on [tensorflow/tensorflow#33340](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33340#issuecomment-541979265). That answer suggests passing `experimental_run_tf_function=False` into the `model.compile` call to revert to the TF 1.x version of model execution. You can also omit the `model.compile` call entirely (it is not necessary for prediction).

> How large does the input need to be to be classified as a large scale input, and for the `model.predict(x)` to perform better?

This is something you can test. As the documentation states, `model(x)` will likely be faster than `model.predict(x)` if your data fit in one batch. One thing that `model.predict(x)` provides over `model(x)` is the ability to predict on multiple batches. If you want to predict on multiple batches with `model(x)`, you have to write the loop yourself. [`model.predict`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) also provides other features, like callbacks.

FYI the documentation in the source code was added in commit [42f469be0f3e8c36624f0b01c571e7ed15f75faf](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/42f469be0f3e8c36624f0b01c571e7ed15f75faf), as a result of [tensorflow/tensorflow#33340](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33340).

The main behavior of `model.predict(x)` is implemented [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/564b53c86efe1d6fa5ad40c4900e41f2967fa73d/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py#L399-L478). It contains more than just the forward pass of the model. This could account for some of the speed differences.

> I've tested with x containing 1; 1,000,000; and 10,000,000 rows and model(x) still performs better.

Do these 10,000,000 rows fit into one batch...?

Comment: Thank you for this. I guess I don't know enough about all this to really understand what is happening. Would a batch be whatever amount of data I can fit into (GPU) memory?

Comment: The batch size is the number of examples used in one iteration of the model. You could set your batch size to whatever you can fit onto your GPU, but too large of a batch size can lead to overfitting ([Keskar et al., 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04836)).