# Keras inconsistent prediction time

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I tried to get an estimate of the prediction time of my keras model and realised something strange. Apart from being fairly fast normally, every once in a while the model needs quite long to come up with a prediction. And not only that, those times also increase the longer the model runs. I added a minimal working example to reproduce the error.

```py
import time
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten

# Make a dummy classification problem
X, y = make_classification()

# Make a dummy model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu',name='input',input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax',name='predictions'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, verbose=0, batch_size=20, epochs=100)

for i in range(1000):
    # Pick a random sample
    sample = np.expand_dims(X[np.random.randint(99), :], axis=0)
    # Record the prediction time 10x and then take the average
    start = time.time()
    for j in range(10):
        y_pred = model.predict_classes(sample)
    end = time.time()
    print('%d, %0.7f' % (i, (end-start)/10))
```

The time does  not depend on the sample (it is being picked randomly). If the test is repeated, the indices in the for loop where the prediction takes longer are going to be (nearly) the same again.

[image]

I'm using:

```
tensorflow 2.0.0
python 3.7.4
```

For my application I need to guarantee the execution in a certain time. This is however impossible considering that behaviour. What is going wrong? Is it a bug in Keras or a bug in the tensorflow backend?

EDIT:
`predict_on_batch` shows the same behavior, however, more sparse:
[image]

`y_pred = model(sample, training=False).numpy()` shows some heavy outliers as well, however, they are not increasing.
[image]

EDIT 2:
I downgraded to the latest tensorflow 1 version (1.15). Not only is the problem not existent anymore, also the "normal" prediction time significantly improved! I do not see the two spikes as problematic, as they didn't appear when I repeated the test (at least not at the same indices and linearly increasing) and are percentual not as large as in the first plot.
[image]

We can thus conclude that this seems to be a problem inherent to tensorflow 2.0, which shows similar behaviour in other situations as @OverLordGoldDragon mentions.

Comment: That behavior sounds predictable.... the increase is sort of linear. If you include this behavior in your time calculation, will it not go? --- I don't know what is happening there.... but what happens if you try with `predict_on_batch` instead?

Comment: Another attempt, what happens with `y_pred = model(sample).numpy()` and with `y_pred = model(sample, training=False).numpy()`?

Comment: I added my findings. The numpy versions don't seem to show the behavior.

Comment: But `predict_classes` is still the fastest.... it seems. What about just `predict`?

Comment: Actually both of them are by far faster than `predict_classes`. I increased the loop to 100 to even be able to measure the time and did not divide the result in the end. `predict` shows the same behaviour as `predict_classes`.

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense....

Comment: I assume this might be some type of memory cleaning....

Comment: Do you want to guarantee the time of many iterations or a single?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TF2 generally exhibits poor and bug-like memory management in several instances I've encountered - brief description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441514/why-is-tensorflow-2-much-slower-than-tensorflow-1#answer-58653632) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33487#issuecomment-585221997). With prediction in particular, the most performant feeding method is via `model(x)` directly - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58378374/why-does-keras-model-predict-slower-after-compile/#answer-58385156), and its linked discussions.

In a nutshell: `model(x)` acts via its its `__call__` method (which it inherits from [`base_layer.Layer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L703)), whereas `predict()`, `predict_classes()`, etc. involve a dedicated loop function via [`_select_training_loop()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L480); each utilize different data pre- and post-processing methods suited for different use-cases, and `model(x)` in 2.1 was designed specifically to yield fastest small-model / small-batch (and maybe any-size) performance (and still fastest in 2.0).

Quoting a [TensorFlow dev](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33340#issuecomment-574470071) from linked discussions:

> You can predict the output using model call, not model predict, i.e., calling `model(x)` would make this much faster because there are no "conversion to dataset" part, and also it's directly calling a cached `tf.function`.

*Note*: this should be less of an issue in 2.1, and especially 2.2 - but test each method anyway. Also I realize this doesn't directly answer your question on the time spikes; I suspect it's related to Eager caching mechanisms, but the surest way to determine is via [`TF Profiler`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras#profiler_apis), which is [broken](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/3256) in 2.1.

---

**Update**: regarding *increasing* spikes, possible GPU throttling; you've done ~1000 iters, try 10,000 instead - eventually, the increasing should stop. As you noted in your comments, this doesn't occur with `model(x)`; makes sense as one less GPU step is involved ("conversion to dataset").

**Update2**: you could bug the devs [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33487#issuecomment-588480988) about it if you face this issue; it's mostly me singing there

Comment: This is a good answer to why one method is slower, but it doesn't explain the increasing run time over multiple runs.

Comment: @LLSv2.0 Not entirely sure myself, but updated answer - I'm still awaiting a response from devs when I raised this issue myself [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33487#issuecomment-585221997)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try going back to TF1 and see what happens there. As for the GPU explanation: I don't think it's correct, as I'm training and predicting solely on CPU.

Comment: @ga97dil Yeah, then I'm out of explanations - try asking on Github, though you may face lengthy response times.

Comment: I downgraded to tensorflow 1.15. No increasing spikes and nearly 10 times faster prediction speed. It's incredible.. The true reason for this is probably beyond me. For now i'll keep using TF1 and stay away from 2.

Comment: If Tensorflow/Keras didn't have a better result over Pytorch, I would have switched to Torch, it's waaaaaaaay faster. Only pure TF1 has comparable speed.

Comment: @ga97dil Indeed, TF1 can be [much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441514/why-is-tensorflow-2-much-slower-than-tensorflow-1) than TF2 - though TF 2.1 is worth trying for small models & datasets, as it's the fastest in training in my benchmarks (didn't do prediction). More importantly, if you ever use TF2, I strongly suggest you test _reproducibility_ in Graph vs. Eager; results can differ _extremely_ in TF 2.1.

Comment: I've added your post to the [Git thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33487#issuecomment-588480988), and my TF2 vs. TF1 post. Thanks for informing me that the problem disappears in TF 1.

Answer (score 2):

While I can't explain the inconsistencies in execution time, I can recommend that you try to convert your model to TensorFlow Lite to speed up predictions on single data records or small batches.

I ran a benchmark on this model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(384, activation='elu', input_shape=(256,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(384, activation='elu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='elu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='elu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='tanh')
])
```

The prediction times for single records were:

1. `model.predict(input)`: 18ms
2. `model(input)`: 1.3ms
3. Model converted to TensorFlow Lite: 43us

The time to convert the model was 2 seconds.

The class below shows how to convert and use the model and provides a `predict` method like the Keras model. Note that it would need to be modified for use with models that don’t just have a single 1-D input and a single 1-D output.

```
class LiteModel:

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, model_path):
        return LiteModel(tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path))

    @classmethod
    def from_keras_model(cls, kmodel):
        converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(kmodel)
        tflite_model = converter.convert()
        return LiteModel(tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model))

    def __init__(self, interpreter):
        self.interpreter = interpreter
        self.interpreter.allocate_tensors()
        input_det = self.interpreter.get_input_details()[0]
        output_det = self.interpreter.get_output_details()[0]
        self.input_index = input_det["index"]
        self.output_index = output_det["index"]
        self.input_shape = input_det["shape"]
        self.output_shape = output_det["shape"]
        self.input_dtype = input_det["dtype"]
        self.output_dtype = output_det["dtype"]

    def predict(self, inp):
        inp = inp.astype(self.input_dtype)
        count = inp.shape[0]
        out = np.zeros((count, self.output_shape[1]), dtype=self.output_dtype)
        for i in range(count):
            self.interpreter.set_tensor(self.input_index, inp[i:i+1])
            self.interpreter.invoke()
            out[i] = self.interpreter.get_tensor(self.output_index)[0]
        return out

    def predict_single(self, inp):
        """ Like predict(), but only for a single record. The input data can be a Python list. """
        inp = np.array([inp], dtype=self.input_dtype)
        self.interpreter.set_tensor(self.input_index, inp)
        self.interpreter.invoke()
        out = self.interpreter.get_tensor(self.output_index)
        return out[0]
```

The complete benchmark code and a plot can be found here:
https://medium.com/@micwurm/using-tensorflow-lite-to-speed-up-predictions-a3954886eb98

Comment: Cool, never tried it before but maybe it would be worth a shot. Thanks for the hint!