# Difference between tf.data.TextLineDataset and tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, text-files, tf.data.dataset

Open a Google colab notebook and run below statements

```
#
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
import os
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset('/content/sample_data/california_housing_test.csv')
dataset ## output is <TextLineDatasetV2 shapes: (), types: tf.string>
```

Then run below

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
import os
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset('/content/sample_data/california_housing_test.csv',batch_size=5)
dataset ## output is <PrefetchDataset shapes: OrderedDict([(longitude, (5,)), (latitude, (5,)), (housing_median_age, (5,)), (total_rooms, (5,)), (total_bedrooms, (5,)), (population, (5,)), (households, (5,)), (median_income, (5,)), (median_house_value, (5,))]), types: OrderedDict([(longitude, tf.float32), (latitude, tf.float32), (housing_median_age, tf.float32), (total_rooms, tf.float32), (total_bedrooms, tf.float32), (population, tf.float32), (households, tf.float32), (median_income, tf.float32), (median_house_value, tf.float32)])>
```

Clearly there is huge difference in the way tf.data.TextLineDataset and tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset handles text file. Why does tensorflow has these two one under experimental and other outside.

Answer (score 0):

The [tf.data.TextLineDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TextLineDataset) loads text from text files and creates a dataset where each line of the files becomes an element of the dataset.

Where as [tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset), it reads CSV files into a dataset, where each element of the dataset is a (features, labels) tuple that corresponds to a batch of CSV rows. The file_pattern should be list of files or patterns of file paths containing CSV records.

`tf.experimental` indicates that the said class/method is in early development, incomplete, or less commonly, not up-to-standards. For more information you can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58333539/14290681)